# Django 3 set django_language cookie

Tags: django, django-i18n

In my application the user can store the preferred language. After selecting the language this is stored in the user model an I set the session variables like this:

```
current_user = request.user
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = current_user.language
request.session[settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME] = current_user.language
```

But the 'django_language' cookie does not change at all and pages are not translated. I found [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language) which tells me exactly the same. Is this still valid for Django3? I also have the middleware 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' set and all messages are compiled. What may be the cause pages are not translated?

Comment: You need to store this in the *response*, since that are the cookies that are communicated back to the client.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem your answer is correct, thx

Comment: Do you have a working example?